# Issue converting list to Dataframe

Tags: python, pokeapi

I'm trying to convert a list to a DF, but for some reason, the DF is not converting with the right information.
I made a function that uses the pokeapi to create a list of pokemon with some other information (height, weight, etc..)

Here it's how it looks and what I'm getting

My function

result = []

def pokemon(x):

```
while x < 5:
    x=x +1
    url_stat = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + str (x)
   #     for x in range(len(url_stat)):
    response_stat = requests.get(url_stat)
    pokelist= pd.json_normalize(json.loads(response_stat.text))[['id','name','height','weight','base_experience']]
    result.append(pokelist)
return result
```

and this is how it looks.. i need to eliminate the "columns" tag from the rows ..

```
pokemon(0)

[   id       name  height  weight  base_experience
 0   1  bulbasaur       7      69               64,
    id     name  height  weight  base_experience
 0   2  ivysaur      10     130              142,
    id      name  height  weight  base_experience
 0   3  venusaur      20    1000              236,
    id        name  height  weight  base_experience
 0   4  charmander       6      85               62,
    id        name  height  weight  base_experience
 0   5  charmeleon      11     190              142]


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':result})
df2.head()

id
0   id name height weight base_experie...
1   id name height weight base_experienc...
2   id name height weight base_experien...
3   id name height weight base_experi...
4   id name height weight base_experi...
```

any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HMFA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have done is right, but **pd.json_normalize()** returns dataframe so you have to convert it into list to get the final dataframe.

```
x=0
result=[]
while x < 5:
    x=x +1
    url_stat = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + str (x)
   #     for x in range(len(url_stat)):
    response_stat = requests.get(url_stat)
    pokelist= pd.json_normalize(json.loads(response_stat.text))[['id','name','height','weight','base_experience']].values.tolist()[0]
    result.append(pokelist)

df=pd.DataFrame(result,columns=['id','name','height','weight','base_experience'])
df

    id  name    height  weight  base_experience
0   1   bulbasaur   7   69      64
1   2   ivysaur     10  130     142
2   3   venusaur    20  1000    236
3   4   charmander  6   85      62
4   5   charmeleon  11  190     142
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the JSON data, drop all the unnecessary data. Keep appending them to your result list. Create a dataframe finally once you fetch all the data.

```
required_tags = ['id','name','height','weight','base_experience']
result = []

x = 0
while x < 5:
    x=x +1
    url_stat = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + str (x)
    response_stat = requests.get(url_stat)
    pokemon_data = response_stat.json()
    for key in list(pokemon_data.keys()):
      if key not in required_tags:
        del pokemon_data[key]
    result.append(pokemon_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)[required_tags]
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. If you convert you dataframe to a string then you can strip the headers from it, and you can append them to results. See code below

```
result.append(pokelist.to_string(header=False))
```